# What is it that's expected from the operation

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model

I've got a regression model and I've got 12 observations. So, I could and I did create the matrix. I also calculated the OLS estimator. But my professor's question is to find X and Y. I'm new to stats and what is don't understand is that if the value of X and Y have already been provided through table what is it that he expects me to find??? Would really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on my problem...

Comment: It may be just a simple comprehension check; beyond that I have no idea. It does seem like a goofy question.

Comment: Hey gung, thanks for your opinion. Do you think that the prof might be expecting me to give predicted value of Y? Even then he should have specified prediction for some specific value of X...

Comment: I really don't know. From what you've related, it sounds like he may want you to show that you can read & understand what's in the table, or maybe it's a very poorly put question asking for something else, or maybe you had misunderstood the question, or maybe another option. I can't tell. Based on what you've given here, I might go w/ the 1st option.

Comment: Thanks anyways for your advice I will consider this question closed...

Comment: You needn't close the question. It's often a while before questions are answered. If you can wait up to a day or so, other (more informative) answers may come along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the instruction means to define *Y* in terms of *X*, and then vice versa, using the regression constant and coefficient you've calculated.  In other words, you need to say that (filling in numerical values for *a* and *b*) *Y* = *a* + *bX* + *e*.